# Runge-Kutta 4th-Order

Tags: c++, runge-kutta

Right now I am trying to make my Runge-Kutta work. Actually I have to solve a ODE-System which is a lot more complicated than this ODE-System, but the runge-kutta-function is the same. I'm solving this simple system to check if the simulation converges to the analytical solution.

First of all I would like to ask you if you see any mistakes in my code. The Problem is, that I get a solution but it differs from the analytical solution (solved it via symbolab). Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

double fx(double x, double y){
    return y;
}

double fy(double x, double y){
    return x + y;
}

void runge_kutta(double dt, double &x, double &y){
    vector<double> k(4), l(4);

    #define dt_half dt/2.0
    #define dt_six dt/6.0

    k.at(0)=fx(x, y);
    l.at(0)=fy(x,y);

    k.at(1)=fx(x+dt_half*k.at(0), y+dt_half*l.at(0));
    l.at(1)=fx(x+dt_half*l.at(0), y+dt_half*l.at(0));

    k.at(2)=fx(x+dt_half*k.at(1), y+dt_half*l.at(1));
    l.at(2)=fx(x+dt_half*l.at(1), y+dt_half*l.at(1));

    k.at(3)=fx(x+dt*k.at(2), y+dt*l.at(2));
    l.at(3)=fy(x+dt*k.at(2), y+dt*l.at(2));

    x+=dt_six*(k.at(0)+2.0*k.at(1)+2.0*k.at(2)+k.at(3));
    y+=dt_six*(l.at(0)+2.0*l.at(1)+2.0*l.at(2)+l.at(3));


}

double t=10.0;
double dt=1e-3;

double x=0.0;
double y=1.0;

ofstream out;

int main(){
    out.open("out.txt");
    out << "#t, x, y" << endl;
    for(double time=0.0;time<t;time+=dt){
        cout<<time<<endl;
        out << time << ' '
            << x << ' '
            << y << ' '
            << endl;
        runge_kutta(dt, x, y);
    }
    out.close();  
}
```

Can you see any errors?

I'm thankful in advance for any help!

Comment: Please add sample input, expected output, and real output from the program.

Comment: Your `l_2` and `l_3` are using the wrong function, are they not? Also, why do you even have an `l` in the first place?

Comment: @Ext3h Because it's 2-dim, or am i missing something?

Comment: _"Debug my code for me"_ is off-topic here. Please read [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and use a [debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953). You need to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post. 
At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have highlighted several inconsistencies in the RK4 code

[image: fig1]

Anything that deals with *y* should call `fy` and have derivative `l` and anything that deals with *x* has derivative `k`.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at these lines

```
l.at(1)=fx(x+dt_half*l.at(0), y+dt_half*l.at(0));
l.at(2)=fx(x+dt_half*l.at(1), y+dt_half*l.at(1));
```

they should use fy instead of fx I think.